# Adding Links with BeautifulSoup. Can't get past special characters

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm am using the Python `calendar` package to create an HTML calendar, but want each date to be a link since the Python `calendar` just displays a text date. I am using `BeautifulSoup4` to find all the elements and replace them with a link. However, when I do this, it changes my greater and less than symbols to `&gt;` and `&lt`. I have even tried forcing it with `unescape` in the `html` python package. It does the same thing.

```
cal = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
soup = BeautifulSoup(cal.formatmonth(2019, 11))
```

Creates:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
   <tr>
    <th class="month" colspan="7">
     November 2019
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th class="sun">
     Sun
    </th>
    <th class="mon">
     Mon
    </th>
    <th class="tue">
     Tue
    </th>
    <th class="wed">
     Wed
    </th>
    <th class="thu">
     Thu
    </th>
    <th class="fri">
     Fri
    </th>
    <th class="sat">
     Sat
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     1
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     2
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     3
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     4
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     5
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     6
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     7
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     8
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     9
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     10
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     11
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     12
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     13
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     14
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     15
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     16
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     17
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     18
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     19
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     20
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     21
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     22
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     23
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     24
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     25
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     26
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     27
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     28
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     29
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     30
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

So here I try to replace the text strings with links:

```
for elem in soup.find_all('td', class_=['sun', 'mon', 'tues', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat']):
    elem.string = '<a href="{}.html">'.format(elem.string) + elem.string + '</a>'
```

Which creates:

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <html><body><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
<tr><th class="month" colspan="7">November 2019</th></tr>
<tr><th class="sun">Sun</th><th class="mon">Mon</th><th class="tue">Tue</th><th class="wed">Wed</th><th class="thu">Thu</th><th class="fri">Fri</th><th class="sat">Sat</th></tr>
<tr><td class="noday"> </td><td class="noday"> </td><td class="noday"> </td><td class="noday"> </td><td class="noday"> </td><td class="fri">&lt;a href="1.html"&gt;1&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="sat">&lt;a href="2.html"&gt;2&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="sun">&lt;a href="3.html"&gt;3&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="mon">&lt;a href="4.html"&gt;4&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="tue">5</td><td class="wed">&lt;a href="6.html"&gt;6&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="thu">&lt;a href="7.html"&gt;7&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="fri">&lt;a href="8.html"&gt;8&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="sat">&lt;a href="9.html"&gt;9&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="sun">&lt;a href="10.html"&gt;10&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="mon">&lt;a href="11.html"&gt;11&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="tue">12</td><td class="wed">&lt;a href="13.html"&gt;13&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="thu">&lt;a href="14.html"&gt;14&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="fri">&lt;a href="15.html"&gt;15&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="sat">&lt;a href="16.html"&gt;16&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="sun">&lt;a href="17.html"&gt;17&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="mon">&lt;a href="18.html"&gt;18&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="tue">19</td><td class="wed">&lt;a href="20.html"&gt;20&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="thu">&lt;a href="21.html"&gt;21&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="fri">&lt;a href="22.html"&gt;22&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="sat">&lt;a href="23.html"&gt;23&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="sun">&lt;a href="24.html"&gt;24&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="mon">&lt;a href="25.html"&gt;25&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="tue">26</td><td class="wed">&lt;a href="27.html"&gt;27&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="thu">&lt;a href="28.html"&gt;28&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="fri">&lt;a href="29.html"&gt;29&lt;/a&gt;</td><td class="sat">&lt;a href="30.html"&gt;30&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>>
```

How do I get `BeautifulSoup4` to actually put in a link?

### Intended Result:

```
<tr>
    <td class="sun">
     <a href="3.index.html">3</a>
    </td>
<<<etc>>>
```

Comment: For HTML _text_, that's correct, otherwise it would be invalid HTML. You need to add the `<a>` tag as a child element to the `<td>`, not as text _in_ the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of my comment, you need to insert a new tag, not modify the text of `<td>`:

```
for elem in soup.find_all('td', class_=['sun', 'mon', 'tues', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat']):
    # Grab the current element text
    # I got weird behavior where it would always use the last element's string if I didn't do this
    text = elem.string
    elem.string = ''

    # Create new tag using "elem"'s text
    new = soup.new_tag('a', href="{}.html".format(text))
    new.string = text

    # Insert <a> tag
    elem.append(new)
```

This produces:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="month">
   <tr>
    <th class="month" colspan="7">
     November 2019
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th class="sun">
     Sun
    </th>
    <th class="mon">
     Mon
    </th>
    <th class="tue">
     Tue
    </th>
    <th class="wed">
     Wed
    </th>
    <th class="thu">
     Thu
    </th>
    <th class="fri">
     Fri
    </th>
    <th class="sat">
     Sat
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="noday">
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     <a href="1.html">
      1
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     <a href="2.html">
      2
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     <a href="3.html">
      3
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     <a href="4.html">
      4
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     5
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     <a href="6.html">
      6
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     <a href="7.html">
      7
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     <a href="8.html">
      8
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     <a href="9.html">
      9
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     <a href="10.html">
      10
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     <a href="11.html">
      11
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     12
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     <a href="13.html">
      13
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     <a href="14.html">
      14
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     <a href="15.html">
      15
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     <a href="16.html">
      16
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     <a href="17.html">
      17
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     <a href="18.html">
      18
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     19
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     <a href="20.html">
      20
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     <a href="21.html">
      21
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     <a href="22.html">
      22
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     <a href="23.html">
      23
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="sun">
     <a href="24.html">
      24
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="mon">
     <a href="25.html">
      25
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="tue">
     26
    </td>
    <td class="wed">
     <a href="27.html">
      27
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="thu">
     <a href="28.html">
      28
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="fri">
     <a href="29.html">
      29
     </a>
    </td>
    <td class="sat">
     <a href="30.html">
      30
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Your expected output included "index" in the `href` url, but based on your question and sample HTML, I'm not sure where you're expecting that to come from. If you need it, you can just put it into the `format` call.

Comment: Thanks. My biggest problem is that I just don't know HTML all that well. Thank you.